# Ruby Continuation-heavy application SLOW

Tags: ruby, continuation

I'm trying to run a Continuation-heavy project in Ruby, and it's terribly slow... I even tried to insert GC.start lines at key points in the code to speed things up, assuming memory was clogged up, and that's didn't help. I tried running Maglev but I use too many gems that are incompatible with it.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is a *continuation-heavy* project?

Comment: Profile your code to find bottlenecks and if you find a bit of code that seems unreasonably slow then ask a question about it. There isn't much to say as you question currently stands.

Comment: I've found the problem, but it still doesn't solve my problem completely - when using recursion and continuations Ruby does a lot of copying that smothers memory and doesn't GC. I've rewritten the algorithm in JS on top of Rhino.